# Use private in public function

Tags: solidity

We cannot use private function outside of the contract. If I define any private function then use it in the public function which is in the same contract with private function. Can I call this public function outside of the contract ? Public function can be called from outside of the contract, but it has private function call in it.

Comment: Yes you can use a private function in a public function and then call the public function. It is similar to Java

Comment: Similar question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40625/how-to-call-a-private-smart-contract-function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a common practice in Solidity.